# What is the difference between function and function(_:) in Swift?

Tags: swift, double

I've recently used `flatMap` to map `String?` to `Double?` in Swift. Calling:

```
optionalString.flatMap(Double.init)
```

and

```
optionalString.flatMap(Double.init(_:))
```

produces the same result. I have two questions:

- Is there a difference between `Double.init` and `Double.init(_:)`?
- I did not think that you can use function signatures in real Swift code. What are some other examples where you can use these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no difference between `Double.init` and `Double.init(_:)`.
These are called first class functions in Swift.
For example:

```
extension UIView {
    func addSubviews(_ views: UIView...) {
    views.forEach(addSubview)
  }
}
```

More info: [First class functions in Swift](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/first-class-functions-in-swift/)

Edit: There is a difference between `Double.init` and `Double.init(_:)`. ( check comments )

Comment: This is not true. When using `.init` Swift will infer which initializer to use regardless of its signature while `.init(_:)` it will try to match only the ones with a single parameter that doesn't require its name